# iPhone landscape scrolls even on empty page

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, safari

I noticed something strange which seems to occur on iPhone Safari only:

If the content is not higher than the viewport its possible to scroll a little bit anyway. Its even possible to scroll a little bit on an empty page. (The height of the Safari topbar?)

Screenshots:
[image]

[image]

I dont see this issue on iPhone Portrait or iPad. I tried iOS 8 and 9 in Simulator.

I'm creating an webapp and don't want this to happen if the body is not higher than 100% of the viewport.

Try it out:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        html, body {
            overflow:hidden;
        }
    </style>

    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no,maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    123
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Updated Answer:

Best solution I found was to remove on-default move events. This does not remove the ability to have links and functions but prevent the page from being scrollable. You would then design your pages using @media to create custom css for landscape/portrait and various screen sizes. link for @media example in comments. You could then implement scrollbars through jquery or javascript. since IOS 8  `minimal-ui`  for viewport meta has been removed and there is no simple way around the screen height issue for landscape.

```js
document.ontouchmove = function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

```css
    html, body {
        overflow: hidden;
        position: fixed;
    }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no,maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
     123456
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry but its not working. I can still scroll in landscape. Did you tried on iPhone or Simulator?

Comment: your right, it doesn't, in your example code I had the scroll bars in portrait and forgot to check landscape. After a quick google I found that you would have to create separate styles based on the orientation using @ media. tutorials can be found here: [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately the content cant be scrolled at all then. Lets say we have a list: 2 items cant be scrolled anymore thats good. But for 200 items i cant scroll and see more than 10. Btw. i think your link is wrong, it links to media query :)

Comment: Media query is correct, the link shows you possible actions and at the bottom links to examples.You would add custom scrollbars within a div to add your scrollbars back using something like https://plugins.jquery.com/slimScroll/. You have not disabled move events, you have just disabled the default behavior. But in saying that, if you know or can calculate if the page is going to be too big, then you can just omit from disabling the default move function.